# Manage multiple versions of a project for multiple customers

Tags: git, customization

I am working on a web application (Symfony 4 rest API) which will be use by multiple customer (about 20 different customers). Each customer has his specific needs so I have to fork the web application for each customer in order to implement the specific needs.

My first idea was to create a common core project in a Git repo with all the source code and to add it as a Git submodule in all other customer projects. Each customer project will implement his specific needs on the common core project.
**Problem :** how to "override" a common core project file in a customer project ? How to manage a correction in the common core project if it has been overriden in a customer project ? I think this solution doesn't work.

So, according to me there are 2 "solutions" to manage it :

**A)** Create a base project not dedicated to a specific customer in one Git repository and fork it for each customer project. When I have to apply a correction in the base project I will use the cherry-pick Git command to apply it on each customer projects repository. So there is no "link" between the projects as they are managed in separated repositories.

**B)** Create one unique Git repository with the base project and create branches for each customer projects : 4 branches for each customer project. 
For example :

(base project)

- master
- dev
- feature
- fix

...

- customerA/master
- customerA/dev
- customerA/feature
- customerA/fix

...

- customerB/master
- customerB/dev
- customerB/feature
- customerB/fix

etc.

so 4 * N branches for N customer projects...

What is the best solution according to you ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would depend on how different your codebases are expected to get.

If they won't diverge much, I'd go with option 2. I like having all the code in the same repo.

However if you expect bigger divergences, it might make more sense to split the code into different projects, and make intelligent use of interfaces and factories, so that you could mix the core code with particular implementations of processes for each client (without reverting to hacks or overwriting files). With this approach I'd have a core project with a default implementation of processes, and each client project would add alternative processes that can be integrated via configuration with the core project as a base.